# Retrieve associated tasks from custom workflow activity

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity

I created an custom workflow activity specified here: [SPWeb.GetListItem returns null in custom workflow activity](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17353/spweb-getlistitem-returns-null-in-custom-workflow-activity)

Now I need to know the user who **last updated** the associated workflow task.

Before my workflow activity is executed, the workflow would "Collect data from a user". When that user provides requested data, the workflow proceeds to execute my custom activity.

Now, I know this can be defined as a property of the activity, but I need to retrieve this automatically (if possible). So far, this is what I have:

`var taskList = __Context.Web.Lists[new Guid(__Context.TaskListGuid)];`

And I was thinking of getting the **"last"** associated task with something **like** this:

```
// get a reference to the task list
var taskList = __Context.Web.Lists[new Guid(__Context.TaskListGuid)];
// find all tasks which were created by this workflow instance
var items = taskList.Items.Where(i => i.AssociatedItemId == __Context.ItemId).OrderByDescending(i => i.LastUpdated);
// get the task that was updated most recently
var lastItem = items.FirstOrDefault();
// get the user who updated that task
var user = lastItem.UpdatedBy
```

Obviously, this is not the actual code, but an idea I have in my mind. Is this the right way to do this? if so, how can I go about it (actual code)?

Comment: Try to use CAML Query for getting tasks, also it is more correctly with performance point.

example of query:
<Query>
  <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="ID" />
        <Value Type="Integer">1</Value>
      </Eq>
  </Where>
  <OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending='FALSE' />
  </OrderBy>
</Query>